# Efficient query for distinct count and group with two columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Given a simple model that consists of descriptions, tags, and some other fields

The results should be:

- a list of all tags in Entry.all without duplicates (e.g. Entry.select("DISTINCT(tag)") )
- the number of duplicates for each tag, also used to sort tags
- all descriptions for each tag sorted alphabetically, again without duplicates  (however, the exactly same description can exist with a different tag)

Is it possible to combine this in one (efficient) query?

Edit:

```
def change
  create_table :entries do |t|
    t.datetime :datum, :null => false                            
    t.string :description                                        
    t.string :tag                                                
    (and some others)
  end

  add_index :entries, :user_id
end
```

Comment: please can you include the table structures in your question?

Comment: I already mentioned those in the first line, now included...

Comment: And what is the criteria for description column? In your model tags with the same names can have different descriptions.

Comment: Yes, that is right. The description is not the description of the tags  ;)

Comment: Ok, but my question is still alive. We're selecting uniq tags with their count (`select tag, count(tag) as total from entries group by tag`) - that's ok. And now we need to add 'description' column to results. For example, we have three similar tags and three different descriptions, after grouping we have one tag and what description do you need for it? The only thought is `select tag, count(tag) as total, min(description) as description from entries group by tag` or in AR: `Entry.all(:select => 'tag, count(tag) as total, min(description) as description', :group => 'tag')`

Comment: Let's assume, the data contains 5 times tag "A" with the descriptions "a, b, a, b, c". And 3 times tag "B" with descriptions "a, a, y". The result should be A: (5) (a, b, c), B: (3) (a, y). It's complicated...

Answer (score -1):

It's better to create additional table:

```
rails g model Tag name:string description:string
rails g model Entry tag:references ...
```

And then just call them:

```
@entries = Entry.select('tag_id, count(tag_id) as total').group(:tag_id).includes(:tag)
```

After that, you will have all descriptions in your object:

```
@entries.first.tag.description # description of entry tag
@entries.first.tag.total # total number of such kind of tags
```

P.S.: Why just one tag per entry?

Comment: In this particular setting the tables and databases exist, there is no option to make a separate table. And second, description does not describe tag, those are not really related. Think of tag as a category and description as a description of a particular entry in that category.